# React router 5, useHistory with 2 Routers

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my app I have 2 routers, something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <LazyRoute exact path='/' component={Main} />
    <LazyRouteLayout path='/path1' component={RouterStepper} />
```

And `RouterStepper` is:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <StepperContainer />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/path2" component={FeeLookup}/>
```

I'm located at `path1` which is a path on the first BrowserRouter, but when I do:

```
const history = useHistory();
history.push('path2');
```

I get a "Not found". How could I got to path2 with react-router methods, hooks, options, etc, how?

Comment: history.push('/path2') , I think you forgot "/" there

Comment: Don't use `BrowserRouter` more than once. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66834105/2873538). You are incorrectly declaring nested routes, you need to use `${path}/path2` (see the docs). And then `history.push("/path1/path2")`