# Redirecting from one Page to Another in React

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import { Link, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import LoginForm from "./Components/LoginForm";
import Otp from "./Components/Otp";

// import GeoLocation from "./Components/Geolocation"
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      {" "}
      <div className="App">
        <Link to="/">LoginForm</Link>
        <Link to="otp">Otp</Link>
        {/* <GeoLocation/> */}
        <Switch>
          {" "}
          <Route path="/" exact component={LoginForm} />
          <Route path="otp" component={Otp} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./LoginForm.css";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
//import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
//import axios from 'axios';
//import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: "",
      submitting: false,
      error: false,
    };
  }

  onHandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ number: event.target.value });
    console.log("Number is: " + this.state.number);
  };

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.history.push("/otp");
    this.setState({ submitting: true });
    console.log(this.state.number);
    fetch("https://d6a898ba0d80.ngrok.io/api/contacts", {
      method: "POST",
      // credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3002/'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ phone: this.state.number }),
    })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          this.setState({
            error: false,
            submitting: false,
            number: "",
          });
          this.history.push("./Otp");
        } else {
          this.setState({
            error: true,
            submitting: false,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          <div className="container1">
            <h1 className="title">Map App</h1>
          </div>
          <form>
            <div className="formInput">
              <p className="paragraph">User Login</p>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter phone number"
                className="form"
                maxLength="10"
                value={this.state.number}
                onChange={this.onHandleChange}
              />
              <br></br>
              <br></br>
              <button className="button" type="button" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
                {" "}
                Next
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(LoginForm);

// import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import "./LoginForm.css";

// class LoginForm extends Component {

//   render() {
//     return (
//       <div class="background-container">
// <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1231630/moon2.png" alt="" />
// <div class="stars"></div>
// <div class="twinkling"></div>
// <div class="clouds"></div>
// </div>
//     )}}

//     export default LoginForm;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

class Otp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      otp1: "",
      otp2: "",
      otp3: "",
      otp4: "",
      submitting: false,
      error: false,
    };
    this.onHandleChange = this.onHandleChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onHandleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    console.log(
      "Otp is: " + this.state.otp1,
      this.state.otp2,
      this.state.otp3,
      this.state.otp4
    );
  };

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ submitting: true });
    console.log(this.state.otp);
    fetch("https://d6a898ba0d80.ngrok.io/api/contacts/OTP", {
      method: "POST",
      // credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3002/'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        otp1: this.state.otp1,
        otp2: this.state.otp2,
        otp3: this.state.otp3,
        otp4: this.state.otp4,
      }),
    })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          this.setState({
            error: false,
            submitting: false,
            otp1: "",
            otp2: "",
            otp3: "",
            otp4: "",
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            error: true,
            submitting: false,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h3 className="validate_otp">Validate OTP</h3>
        <p className="paragraph">
          Please enter the OTP (one time password) to verify your account. A
          Code has been sent to <span className="text-dark">*******179</span>
        </p>
        <form id="otp-screen" method="post">
          <div className="form-row">
            <div className="col form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="otp_filed"
                maxLength="1"
                name="otp1"
                value={this.state.otp1}
                onChange={this.onHandleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="otp_filed"
                maxLength="1"
                name="otp2"
                value={this.state.otp2}
                onChange={this.onHandleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="otp_filed"
                maxLength="1"
                name="otp3"
                value={this.state.otp3}
                onChange={this.onHandleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="otp_filed"
                maxLength="1"
                name="otp4"
                value={this.state.otp4}
                onChange={this.onHandleChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button className="verify_btn" type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
            Verify
          </button>
        </form>
        {/* <p class="text-center text-muted mb-0">Not received your code? <a class="btn-link" href="#">Resend code</a></p> */}
      </div>
    );
  }**strong text**
```

I want to redirect from login.js file to otp.js file ,,, I tried using react-router-dom with history.push method but I'm getting error like - Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
and it is not redirecting to next page.

Anyone please help me out with this problem!!!

Thank you

[image]

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66834105/2873538)

Comment: Thank You ,,, Redirecting Working Properly

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a slash to your route,

```
<Router>
    {" "}
    <div className="App">
    <Link to="/">LoginForm</Link>
    <Link to="/otp">Otp</Link> // add a slash before your url link
    {/* <GeoLocation/> */}
    <Switch>
        {" "}
        <Route path="/" exact component={LoginForm} />
        <Route path="/otp" component={Otp} /> // add a slash before your url link
    </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

bind **onSubmit** function on constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        number: "",
        submitting: false,
        error: false,
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

onSubmit = (event) => {
    this.props.history.push("/otp");
}
```

if history.push doesn't work from props, you can use **createBrowserHistory** from history

make a **history.js** file

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

now import that file,

```
import history from './path-to-history-file/history';
```

ant then,

```
history.push('/otp');
```