# React-Router: Private route re-renders every time a nested route is hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have 2 react routers; a main router where there are 2 routes `/login`, and `/` which is a protected route; and the second router contains sub-routes for `/`. The protected route renders a **Layout** component that contains a header, sidemenu, footer and the main component, and the **Main** components contains my sub-routes.

```
//App
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
     <ProtectedRoute path="/" component={Layout} />
  </Switch>
</Router>

//Layout
<div className={classes.layout}>
   <Header />
   <div className={classes.content}>
      <SideMenu />
      <Main />
      <Footer />
   </div>
</div>

//Main
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={...} />
     <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={...} />
     <Route exact path="/another" component={...} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

At first I thought that every time I hit the sub-routes only the **Main** component will re-render, until I poked around the Profiler DevTool and it showed that the entire **Layout** component re-rendered. I tried making the **Layout** page a `React.memo` and it did save me some milliseconds but is there a way to actually bypass re-rendering the **Layout** component every time I go to the sub-routes?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66834105/2873538)