# React router links only works on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my App.js.I have code for all the routes here

```
import{BrowserRouter,Switch,Route}from 'react-router-dom'       
import Home from './HOME/Home';
function App() {
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home }/> 
        <Route path="/cpu" exact component={Info}/> 
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
    
export default App;
```

Home.js Where I have Links to webpages

```
import{BrowserRouter}from 'react-router-dom'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
   
function Navs(){
  return(
    ReactDOM.render(
      <div className="Navs">
        <ul>
            <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/cpu">CPU</Link>
        <Link to="/Monitors">MONITORS</Link>
        <Link to="/GPU">GPUS</Link>
        <Link to="/Ram">RAMS</Link>
        <Link to="/Keyboards">KEYBOARDS</Link>
        <Link to="/Mouse">MOUSE </Link> 
        <Link to="/Others">OTHER ACCESORIES</Link>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </ul>
      </div>
      ,document.getElementById('Navs')
    )
  )
}
```

Though I have all the code correctly I am not getting why it's not working. I have tried all the solutions like changing Router to BrowserRouter. When I click on the Link the URL changes. But the same page is shown. It works fine when I refresh the page.

Comment: Are you suing multiple ReactDOM.render? You can only use one and the Navs need to be children of BrowserRouter.

Comment: [You need only one Router at root level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66834105/2873538).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are using more than one `Router`. The nested router around the links is handling the links being clicked and updates the URL in the address bar, but this doesn't allow the outer router handling the routes to be made aware of the address change (*until you reload the page*).

## Solution

Remove the nested `Router`, you need only one routing context for the entire app.

```
<div className="Navs">
  <ul>
    <Link to="/cpu">CPU</Link>
    <Link to="/Monitors">MONITORS</Link>
    <Link to="/GPU">GPUS</Link>
    <Link to="/Ram">RAMS</Link>
    <Link to="/Keyboards">KEYBOARDS</Link>
    <Link to="/Mouse">MOUSE </Link> 
    <Link to="/Others">OTHER ACCESORIES</Link>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You also shouldn't render different parts of your app into different ReactDOM elements (use portals for this if you must). You will also want to remove the extraneous `ReactDOM.render` in the `Nav` and just render `Nav` into the regular JSX likely in `App` within the router being rendered there.

```
function App() {
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Nav />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home }/> 
        <Route path="/cpu" exact component={Info}/> 
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Removing BrowserRouter from Navs gives an error:"cant use Link outside Router"

Comment: @mojo Need to render `Nav` within the `BrowserRouter` rendered in `App`, somewhere within the React subtree rendered by the one router.

Comment: thanks for you help,but still I am not getting what's wrong .The code after the changes looks like this in fiddle  "https://jsfiddle.net/wpkz4xa8/".

Comment: @mojo That jsfiddle doesn't appear to run. Think you could fix it up so it runs, or create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) version that does?

Comment: My intention is to show you the changes I have made to the code. Dont expect that to run.

Comment: @mojo I don't know if you're doing something else in your code to make it not work, but the above solution is one way to resolve your issue and works. See this running [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-links-only-works-on-refresh-y6q6q).

Comment: Got it working ,I am new to react thanks for helping me out